# How can I fix a boot loop after replacing the Power button?

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

A couple days ago my phone started boot looping and just showing the Samsung logo. I was told that my <kbd>Power</kbd> button was the problem, so I replaced it but I'm still having the same issue.

I have a Samsung S4 Mini i9190.

Comment: Did anything else happen before this issue occurred?  Have you tried a Factory Reset from Recovery?  You may need to flash the stock ROM.

Answer (score 0):

You should get it inspected by an Authorised Samsung Service Center. Similar issue happened with one of my Samsung Galaxy Device too, they diagnosed that due to over heating of device while gaming or heavy usage sometime device CPU mounting on motherboard (which is done my lead balls) gets cracked causing connectivity issues between CPU Chip and motherboard, resulting in boot failure, or boot-loop. So in my case they had to replace the motherboard to fix the issue.

Though in your case its not necessary its happening because of same reason as of mine, there can be numerous reason for similar fault. It could be something very minor connectivity issue as well, as most of the Samsung devices cause this error due to corrupt OS and at time due to a faulty charging connector too.

Bst thing is to get it checked from Samsung Authorized Service Personnel/Center.